# x-systemd.growfs in fstab Ubuntu Raspiberry pi 4

Tags: fstab, raspberrypi, 20.10

I installed Ubuntu 20.10 desktop on Raspberry pi 4. The problem is that I installed it on an SSD and I want to resize the root partition, leaving 11 to 12 GB free space at the end of the partition as over-provisioning.

However, each time I resize and reboot, the partition grows back to full. I noticed `x-systemd.growfs` in `fstab` and I suppose that this is the culprit.

How can I shrink my partition and also add `noatime` in `fstab`?

Answer (score 1):

If the above doesn't work, you can uninstall growroot:

```
sudo apt-get remove  cloud-initramfs-growroot
```

This will ensure the `/` device does not automatically grow to fill the storage medium with every boot.

Answer (score 0):

`x-systemd.growfs` instructs the system to grow the filesystem to "occupy the full block device" ... so the partition (and filesystem) will be grown into the free space.

I can't see from the description if it will overwrite a partition that is placed after the filesystem you are mounting and growing.

You have two possibilities:

1. Remove `x-systemd.growfs` option from `/etc/fstab`.
2. After resizing the filesystem, define a new partition in that free space, and eventually make a filesystem in it too. If that partition is overwritten at next boot, you only have option 1.

I like option 1 the best. This is how Linux has worked for ages. But `x-systemd.growfs` is a nifty tool if you need to grow a filesystem that can't be unmounted (like `/`). However, I would prefer to add it only if it is needed, and remove it after the filesystem has been grown.

You can add `noatime` at the same place where you deleted `x-systemd.growfs` I think. It should be a comma separated list of options. But if you show the line from `fstab`, I can verify if I'm right.

Comment: Nope. I had tried it earlier and I tried it again it still reverts back to full even without the -systemd.growfs in fstab. What could be wrong here?

Comment: I noticed that after removing the x-systemd.growfs the system reports some USB error at boot. but after placing the 'x-systemd.growfs' back into fstab that error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to the question. Run:

```
sudo nano /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
```

Remove:

```
growpart
resizefs
```

Comment: I have found a solution to the problem.
Just uninstall growroot
sudo apt-get remove  cloud-initramfs-growroot.

Comment: I have found a solution to the problem.
Just uninstall growroot
sudo apt-get remove  cloud-initramfs-growroot.